# How do I read the actual query being sent, and the data being received with NpgSql, c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npgsql, amazon-aurora

I have got this code running, and I see no way of logging the actual query being sent, and the data being received.

```
using NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_dbSettings.ConnectionString);
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(commandText, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = commandType;
                conn.Open();

                var result = conn.Query<T>(commandText, parameters, commandType: CommandType.Text);
                
                return result;
            }
```

This is the logger I have as well.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .MinimumLevel.Is(LogEventLevel.Verbose)
               .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
               .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
               .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
               .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
               .WriteTo.Console(
                    outputTemplate:
                    "[{Level:u3}] [{RequestId}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
               .CreateLogger();
```

I am unable to understand which part of my query is failing, since its impossible for me to know what query actually went out, and what data came back.

PS: I am using AWS RDS, tunneled in for local use. Also, I am a beginner in C#

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate Npgsql's logging with whatever logging package you're using above - [see the documentation for that](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/logging.html).